# Git how to add multiple files with similar names?

Tags: git

I have a folder with... let's say 10 files. 6 of which have "user" in the name, and I'd like to add the 6 files easily.

I'm wondering how should I type on 'git add' to get all the files with "user" in the name?

p.s. The "user" sometimes positioned in front, middle, or the end of the file name. Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

It seems that you are asking a very basic operating system question.  You can use a wildcard like this:

`git add *user*`